# How maintain a profile id throughout my application after login

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, session-cookies

In my application after login user, show only that users information. For that i created a user profile table and given each user a unique profile id.

My question is how to maintain  a unique profile id throughout my application after user login. After successful  user id and password creating a cookie ans storing in id in session variable.

Is it good to maintain id in session variable or in cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Session variable. If user login is valid, you can create a Session variable, assign it a value of "member". Create another session, assign it the value of the user's id(using a datareader). Then on the user's profile table, in the Page Load event of the user's profile webform you can check if Session["something"] == "member", and if so you can create an sql connection to the users database, select * from users where user id = session["user_id"](the session variable created previously that contains the user id of the user that managed to log in), and you can display the user data using datareader.

Comment: login page for my website: https://github.com/psychicspies/ASP.NET-Project/blob/master/RiseonicWebsite/Home_Member.aspx.cs and my users profile page: https://github.com/psychicspies/ASP.NET-Project/blob/master/RiseonicWebsite/Customer_Profile_View.aspx.cs. If my customer manages to log in, I create a session variable Session["valid"] = "member'. Also, Session["customer_id"] = dr["customer_id"]. Then in my customer profile page load, I check if Session["valid"] != null, if not null means is "customer", so cr8 conn, select * from table whr customer_id = Session["customer_id"]

Comment: Sorry for the bad reply Im only year 2 in HS so not good at explaining syntactically well, but if you don't understand you can send me your code and I can help you @samuelywp@gmail.com